# Rename all files in directory through terminal

Tags: rename, batch-rename

Say, I have several files in a directory.

How do I rename all of them to "001", "002", etc., saving their current file extensions?

Answer (score 5):

- **Terminal** method
  **cd (change directory) to the folder**.
  run command:
- Command 1

  ```
  rename -n -v 'our $n; my $zn=sprintf("%03d", ++$n); s/.*\./$zn./' *.*
  ```

This will display the changes. Remove -n for actual rename.
Answer from [@Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/504550/rename-files-with-zero-padded-numbers-while-keeping-extension-using-rename-com/504553#504553)

- Command 2

  ```
  a=1; for i in *.*; do new=$(printf "%03d" "$a"); mv -i -- "$i" "$new.${i##*.}"; let a=a+1; done
  ```
- **GUI** method
  Select all files to be renamed.
  Right click and select rename.
  Delete [Original file name] from the option area.
  Click on "Add" and select 001, 002, 003, 004.
  Click on "Rename".

[image: rename-1]

[image: rename-2]

[image]

Comment: Will try tomorrow. Sleepy. It's is late here.

Comment: seems like a lot of work when there are multiple 'rename' commands available.

Comment: @user68186 edited command-line for use "...through terminal"